# SSH to local PC using its external IP

Tags: ssh, networking

I have PC1 and PC2, both under Ubuntu, with active SSH servers, and behind the same router. I will use different bash prompts for the sake of clarity.
I can ssh from PC1 to PC2 using the local IP.

```
[user@PC1]$ ssh user@192.168.0.28
/user@PC2/$ logout
Connection to PC2 closed.
[user@PC1]$ ssh user@PC2.local
/user@PC2/$ logout
Connection to PC2 closed.
[user@PC1]$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
<External IP>
[user@PC1]$ ssh user@PC2.local
/user@PC2/$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
<External IP>
```

**How can I ssh using the external IP (which is the same for both?**

```
[user@PC1]$ ssh user@<External IP> ... etc?
```

**Would the procedure be different from what I would do if PC1 and PC2 were behind different routers?**

Note that I meant to learn how to do this now that I have both PCs at hand, and prepare PC2 for future occasions when I am away.

Comment: you can't - unless you hairpin a port forward on two different ports, then you'd use `-p` option - so, this question is unrelated to unix & linux, as it depends on the capabilities of your router

Comment: @Bravo - Would you mind detailing the procedure?
I expected my requirement to be a *very* usual one, and thus with available solutions (possibly more than one).

Comment: nothing to do with unix & linux, it's a router configuration that will allow this - i.e. nothing you can do on your PC1 and PC2 - `I expected my requirement to be a very usual one` you'd be wrong, why would anyone want to connect to an internal PC from another internal PC using the external IP address of the router? seems like a niche requirement

Comment: @Bravo - You are right in that what I asked is not common.
I actually meant to learn the basics, and later connect PC1->PC2 from elsewhere, assuming the procedure would be exactly the same.
If my assumption is correct (and I added a question about that), then I am on the right track.
If not, this is, from the practical standpoint, an XY Problem. Even in that case, the question and its solutions are still instructive, I guess.

Comment: *Would the procedure be different from what I would do if PC1 and PC2 were behind different routers?* it'd be easier, because you don't have to hairpin two different ports

Comment: Do you need this on a per-need basis, or is this for a permanent setup? If for permanent, the it's a network configuration issue, as @Bravo explained. If it's temporary, only for testing, you could use something like `ngrok` perhaps, but for that you'd have to clarify further.

Comment: @Bravo - Would that amount to simply changing the numbers in the commands, in the appropriate places? 
I the case of connecting from "outside", will I need the same router configuration as in my question? (I guess I would).

Comment: @polemon - I would need this for frequent use. Mostly from outside, but as I mentioned in another comment, I meant to learn the basics now that I have both PCs at hand. I expected the procedure to be the same, other than the need for two different ports if both PCs are behind the same router.

Comment: Well in this case it's not down to the machines, it's down to your network setup. If your machines both already accept SSH connections from the network, you're done there. The rest is configuring the network, such that your external IP is forwarded to one of those computers. You can use something like DynDNS or ngrok to get an address that is easy to access from the internet, etc.

Comment: you want to learn the basics - cool - this is a router setting, that's the basics

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a router configuration issue, nothing to do with UNIX/Linux

Comment: @roaima - I did not know how to do this when I first asked. Knowing now (and I thank the guidance from the comments), I disagree with you. I think it is a matter of *Router configuration* + *Suitable usage of `ssh`*. And if you consider recommended settings for increased security as part of an answer, this also is part of Linux.
I put together an answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments received, and further research with those guidelines, I came to the following conclusions:

**How can I ssh using the external IP (which is the same for both)?**

This involves several steps, some mandatory, some convenient.

1. **Mandatory**. Configure *Port forwarding* in the router. Add a service for port forwarding with the following parameters (this varies across routers):

   - *Custom Name*: e.g., SSH port 23
   - *Service type*: TCP/UDP (typically selected from a menu)
   - *Internal port*: Port # in PC2 (listening for connections), e.g., 22 (default).
   - *Start/End port*: Port # to be used in the `ssh` command in PC (the client). So far, I could only succeed using the same value for both, e.g., 23.
   - *Server IPv4*: local IP of PC2, e.g., `192.168.0.30`.
2. **Mandatory**. Connect via either of

   ```
   [user@PC1]$ ssh user@<External IP> -p 23
   [user@PC1]$ ssh ssh://user@<External IP>:23
   ```
3. **Optional**. Setup a Dynamic DNS, so it is not needed to know the `<External IP>`.
4. **Optional**. Set a fixed IP for PC2, so the Port forwarding service never misses the target.

Notes:

1. One can set, as usual, a different *Internal port*, e.g. 5901, in PC2. Check `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, `ufw`, etc. [Increased safety measures](https://dev.to/zduey/how-to-set-up-an-ssh-server-on-a-home-computer) could be considered.

   - Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` with line `Port 5901` instead of the default commented `#Port 5901`.
   - Set a firewall rule with `$ sudo ufw allow 5901/tcp`.
   - Restart with `$ sudo service ssh restart`.
   - Change the *Internal port* in the router Port forwarding.
2. One could likely ssh to more than one PC behind the same router, by setting up corresponding *Port forwarding* services.

**Would the procedure be different from what I would do if PC1 and PC2 were behind different routers?**

I didn't try this yet, but I suspect it is exactly the same.
When using `[user@PC1]$ ssh user@<External IP> -p 23`, I don't think my router knows (or cares) I am ssh'ing from a PC1 that is actually connected to the internet via itself.

Comment: Note that the whole problem of only one external IP crumbles with IPv6 where your external IPs are unique for each device. Still for an access from external sources, you will need an open firewall. Internally this would usually not be necessary as the router should recognize the IP as from the local network.

Comment: @FelixJN - This is interesting, and I am not aware of the details. I think it would be useful for the community if you posted an answer describing the step to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I ssh using the external IP (which is the same for both?

you can't; you've got **one** external IP, as you said, and on that you have **one** port 22. Your router can't know which one of your PCs you mean.

Two things you could do:

1. Forward two different external ports to PC1:22 and PC2:22, say port 2211 and 2222.
2. set up an SSH server on the router and use it as "jump host" (see the `-J` option in `man ssh`); then you can `ssh -J externalIP user@192.168.0.28`.

> Would the procedure be different from what I would do if PC1 and PC2 were behind different routers?

yes, because these would have differen public IPs.

Comment: Why would you say "You can't" and then explain how "You can, if you do it this way"?

Comment: because in your question you stated the ssh command line you wanted, and that's impossible. You'll need to add the port for the first approach, or specify a jump host for the second.

Comment: Ok, I see. I actually suspected (without knowing) that some extra parameters would be needed, and that is why I added `... etc`. That `etc` is `-p ...`
I guess for the sake of clarity, it is best to start right away with the way to do it. At least as it is now, it confused me a bit.
I put together an answer which, according to what I could test, is representative.